# Square root of inverse of eigen-decomposition of a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A$ is an $n\times p$ matrix and let $A^{T}A=VDV^{T}$ where $VDV^{T}$ is the eigendecomposition of $A^{T}A$. What is the value of $(VDV^{T})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ ? How ?

Comment: If $A^T A = V D V^T$, that must be the eigendecomposition of $A^T A$, not $A A^T$.

Comment: You are correct. Edited it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course $D$ must be invertible for this to exist.  I presume you're using the eigendecomposition where $V$ is orthogonal.  Then $(V D V^T)^{-1/2} = V D^{-1/2} V^T$.  This is because $V^T V = V V^T = I$ and 
$$(V D^{-1/2} V^T)^2 (V D V^T) = V D^{-1/2} V^T V D^{-1/2} V^T V D V^T = 
V D^{-1/2} D^{-1/2} D V^T = V V^T = I$$